# Prolog: reverse list (sublists included)

Tags: list, prolog, reverse

I have written the simple code to reverse a typical integer list:

```
reverse([], []).
reverse([X], [X]).
reverse([X|Y], A) :- reverse(Y, Z), append(Z, [X], A).

? reverse([1, 2, 3], X)
X = [3, 2, 1].
```

However, I am pretty lost, as I am new to prolog, how to reverse a list that has other sublists within it, such as:

```
? reverse([1, [2, 3], [1, [3, [2, 4, 5], 1], 2], 5], X).
X = [5, [2, [1, [5, 4, 2], 3], 1], [3, 2], 1].
```

etc.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to inspect the head of the list in the second and third rules. Use `is_list/1` on `X` in both of those, and if it is true, call reverse on it as well.

Answer (score 1):

This modification of your code works, but it's clumsy:

```
reverse([], []).
reverse([X|Y], A) :- reverse(Y, Z), reverse(X, Xrev), append(Z, [Xrev], A), !.
reverse(X, X). % not a list
```

BTW, `reverse([X], [X]).` clause in your original code is not needed.

*Update* thanks to @mbratch comment:

```
reverse([X|Y], A) :- reverse(Y, Z), reverse(X, Xrev), append(Z, [Xrev], A).
reverse(X, X) :- X \= [_|_]. % X is not a list, or X is an empty list
```

Comment: A slight simplification could be to omit the cut and omit `reverse([], []).` and change `reverse(X, X).` to `reverse(X, X) :- X \= [_|_].` :)

Comment: @mbratch yeah, much better.

Answer (score 1):

The definition can be made very compact:

```
deep_reverse(A, B) :- maplist(deep_reverse, A, R), !, reverse(R, B).
deep_reverse(A, A).
```

I've renamed it to be able to use the library predicate. Generally, I think it's best to avoid redefining library predicates.

Comment: I think you're right about library predicates. But the op my be trying to do it as an exercise. This is still a nice example of using `maplist` (+1).

Comment: @mbratch: thanks. Since Daniel and Sergey already addressed OP's problem, I just provided an insight to library.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any built-ins, you can do:

```
reverse_nested_list( Xs, Rs ) :-
  reverse_nested_list( Xs, [], Rs )
  .

reverse_nested_list( []     , Rs , Rs ) .
reverse_nested_list( [X|Xs] , Ts , Rs ) :-
  is_list(X) ,
  !          ,
  reverse_nested_list(X,[],T) ,
  reverse_nested_list(Xs,[T|Ts],Rs)
  .
reverse_nested_list( [X|Xs] , Ts , Rs ) :-
  reverse_nested_list(Xs,[X|Ts],Rs)
  .

%
% cursory check for list-ness.
% 
is_list(X) :- var(X), !, fail.
is_list([]).
is_list([_|_]).
```

Easy!